# how do I fix the filter map and mapWithState function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am a new scala corder, I have a flatMap function which return a FlatMappedDStream object, it is a sparking streaming job, the handle function return a Map[String, Any], the code is below:

```
val parseAction = filterActions.flatMap(record => ParseOperation.parseMatch(categoryMap, record))
```

function def:

```
val parseMatch = (categoryMap: collection.Map[Int, String], record: Map[String, Any]) => {
record.get("operation").get.toString match {
  case "view" => parseView(categoryMap, record)
  case "impression" => parseRecord(record)
  case "click" => parseRecord(record)
  case _ => ListBuffer.apply(record)

}
```

}

the parseMatch function returns the processed streaming records whose type is Map[String, Any],Now I want to print all results and put in the new filter map function and mapWithState function, I try it but it doesn't work.
the wrong code is below:

```
val finalActions = parseAction.filter(record => record.get("invalid").get == None)

val userModels = finalActions.map(record => (record.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]].getOrElse("deviceid", ""), record))
                       .mapWithState(StateSpec.function(stateUpdateFunction))
```

the mapWithState function is:

```
val stateUpdateFunction = (deviceId: Any, newRecord: Option[Map[String, Any]], stateData: State[Map[String, Any]]) => {
  XXXX
```

}

but the filter function and mapWithState function are not correct, how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed it, I modify my returning type from Map[String,Any] to ListBuffer[Map[String,Any]], it does work!